# HTTP_COOKIE is missing after return from bank

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

the last 2 weeks i am facing with a problem regarding PHP Sessions when the request is returning from bank.

From my site the user is redirecting to the bank to make the payment.

When payment is complete is returning to my site but in some cases the HTTP_COOKIE is missing and i can not raise the Sessions.

This code is working for the last year and i have check all the necessary cases

- session_start on top
- possible http/https wrong redirects

and i don't see any problem.

I don't know what else to check but its seems that either Client browser is removing or Apache is removing HTTP_COOKIE.

Does anyone has any idea where else i should look to fix the problem?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Unlikely that Apache “removed” anything here, much more likely, that the client rejected or discarded the cookie. Is the session already started on a page _before_ you redirect to the banking site, or are you trying to do both in one go? (`session_start(); header('Location: …');`)

Comment: @CBroe Hi the sessions already exists before redirection, the user must first login and go to dashboard and make the payment.I dont use header('Location:..') for redirection.I have a form element that post variables to bank site with auto submit